# Soundcloud 403 error for a range of IPs

Tags: curl, soundcloud

We have several servers, with exactly the same configurations (CentOS 6 + Plesk). On all our servers using an IP range beginning by 51 until 149, when we test this command in the terminal being connected to one of these servers:
`curl -v https://api.soundcloud.com/v1/playlists/29604379.json?consumer_key=xxxxxxxxxx` (with a real key instead of "xxxx")
it always responds with:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 19 Jan 2016 14:15:37 GMT
Server: ECS (pox/A5DD)
Content-Length: 345

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>403 - Forbidden</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>403 - Forbidden</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

While we have the correct response to this request on servers with IP beginning by 5, 37, or , 151. The problem seems to be on servers with IPs between 51 and 149, like if these IPs are blocked by Soundcloud.
We have almost 50 VPS with IPs between 51 and 149, and that's the same for all, while there is no problem on others (around 50 VPS too).

Any help would be very much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, the request work on my local computer but not on my 3 VPS (hosted by OVH and located in Strasbourg and Gravelines) all with IP addresses beginning by 51. (The VPS are on Debian Jessie.)

Comment: I just tested on an other VPS also on Debian Jessie with an IP beginning by 5 and it works well... I hope that the SoundCloud team will see this message since it seems to be difficult to contact the support team.

Comment: Yes, OVH too, but it doesn't seem to be due to OVH VPS, since we have other ones from OVH with the same configuration and in other IP ranges and it works well with these ones. Hope an answer from the Soundcloud team...

Answer (score 3):

Here is an officle answer from soundcloud : 
https://www.soundcloudcommunity.com/soundcloud/topics/403-forbidden-when-using-ovh-vpn

> our Trust & Safety engineers needed to block OVH for SoundCloud, as it
>   was causing a lot of spam and fake activity to come through. :-/