# http requests to /tracks/{id} a 403 status code from AWS other cloud providers, however 200 locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, python-requests, soundcloud

Sending http requests to the `/tracks/{id}` endpoint from any of our AWS boxes, both inside of different VPCs or from EC2 Classic return `403` status codes, however the same http requests sent from local machines return `200` requested data. This happens both using python's requests library and curl.

*edit:*

Tested using Google Compute Engine and Digital Ocean and both display same bad behaviour.

using `?ids` url parameter I am able curl `/tracks?ids=[bad_id]`

i.e.
doesn't work: `curl https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/182343690?client_id=XXX`
works: `curl https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/?client_id=XXX&ids=182343690`

**note**: Neither work inside requests

The following does however work

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("curl https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/?client_id=XXX&ids=182343690", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

Comment: Something I noticed is that a head request `curl -I` tends to always work. See my issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36259753/2248638

Comment: Also, this seems to be the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879513/soundcloud-403-error-for-a-range-of-ips

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's related, but I had some issues with tokens and curl using PHP.

In the end I added the SSL options to my curl request and that solved my issue.

Code snippet

```
try {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  ...
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
  $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
  $body = substr($response, $header_size);      
  $result = $body;
  ...
  curl_close($ch);
} catch(Exception  $e) {
  $this->writeLog('authToken() Error Message: ' .$e->getMessage());
}
```