# Soundcloud API resolve endpoint returning 403 on some track URLs - C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, soundcloud

I am using soundcloud api (in ASP.NET MVC app) to resolve a URL for its track ID for further requesting for CfmediaUrl of found track ID. It works well on around 85% of track urls but throws the following error on remaining tracks

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

I've gone throw most of available posts already on internet which suggests that it might be because of the artist/uploader has reached his download limit or some constraints from the uploader that doesn't allow the request to complete. However all of those URLs work on many other sites like [scdownloader here](http://scdownloader.net/).

This stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978866/soundcloud-api-is-returning-403-on-some-tracks) is similar to my question but yet I can do it on other sites so there's no point of facing this issue because of uploader's restriction. All i want to do is get CfmediaUrl for these tracks. Is there a way out? There are many questions on this topic but most doesn't answer it.