# SoundCloud API return error 403 - Forbidden for all request from my VPS

Tags: soundcloud

I have a simple request to SoundCloud API which I get the correct response in my local. But when I put it into my VPS, the API returned error 403 - Forbidden. I have been looking around and found no document or proper explanation for this. This happening for all requests to SoundCloud API from my VPS (not 50% like the other post that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360202/soundcloud-api-urls-timing-out-and-then-returning-error-403-on-about-50-of-trac)) .

```
    $ curl https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/197355235\?client_id\=978b6cc3cb0ba473f75da8bf6d3d0990

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>403 - Forbidden</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>403 - Forbidden</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same for me.
Seems to be a blacklist but SoundCloud do not respond when you try to contact them...

If your host is OVH, read this :
[Soundcloud 403 error for a range of IPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879513/soundcloud-403-error-for-a-range-of-ips)